# How to have network capabilities for a Java application?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety

I have a Java application that inputs images, gives a number of options to edit them (crop, resize) and then exports them to local storage.

I currently trying to attach a server to this application using java.net but running to several issues as I have never done this before.

1. I have a button on the GUI that activates the Server, so the app can receive commands - The issue is the server uses a while loop that doesn't stop until it disconnects with the client, this means the program can't run until then. I am assuming that it requires creating a new thread but how do I send commands to the app without creating a new instance?
2. I would like to send images from the client to the application through the server. The client currently using JFileChooser to pick an image but how do I send it down the stream and recreate it at the other end?

My code is just a modified version of this [client](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoClient.java) and [server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoServer.java). It just removes the echo feature and runs a method based on the string sent by the client. (e.g. Client sends "open" to server - the server runs open(){} method.

**Edit:
Code:**

This is the server code. The ImageGUI is the GUI with all the commands and holds the openImage method. 
    private int portNumber = 8888;

```
public Server() {

    try (
    // Create Server socket
    ServerSocket theServer = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            // Create socket for client
            Socket clientSocket = theServer.accept();
            // Use to write to client
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                    clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            // Used to read from client
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));) {
        // Waits for Client commands
        String clientCommand;
        while ((clientCommand = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (clientCommand.contains("open")) {
                // Runs open method in ImageGUI
                new ImageGUI().openImage(); // I don't want this because it
                                            // will create another GUI
                                            // I want to run the openImage()
                                            // in the GUI already open
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: `but how do I send commands to the app without creating a new instance` Huh?

Comment: I've added a comment in the code to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a shared [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Queue.html) to send and consume commands.

   BlockingQueue are thread safe. Use `take()` to make your server wait for the next command and use `add()` from your main thread to add a command to the queue.

   You can then use a class, an enum or even strings to represent commands and send them from your main thread to your server thread.
2. To send images, use `OutputStream` from the client (`echoSocket.getOutputStream()`) to write data. Server side, use `InputStream` (`clientSocket.getInputStream()`) to receive data.

   For example:

   ```
   // Client side
   int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
   if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       File imageFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

       try(FileInputStream imageInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
           OutputStream serverOutputStream = echoSocket.getOutputStream()) {
           int[] buffer = new int[1024];
           int readCount = imageInputStream.read(buffer);
           while(readCount > 0) {
               serverOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
               readCount = imageInputStream.read(buffer);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And:

   ```
   // Server side
   File folder = new File("/tmp/");
   File imageFile = new File(folder, "image.jpg");

   try(InputStream clientInputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
           FileOutputStream imageOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile)) {
           int[] buffer = new int[1024];
           int readCount = clientInputStream.read(buffer);
           while(readCount > 0) {
               imageOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
               readCount = clientInputStream.read(buffer);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do want to run your server's `accept()` loop in its own thread.

Your server GUI's 'start server' button will start this thread. Make sure you also have a 'stop server' button which tells the server thread to quit. Also tell the server thread to quit when the user quits the app.

You're going to need to decide on a *protocol* for sending the images.

It could be as simple as pushing the bytes from the image file down the socket, then closing the socket -- or it could be something more complicated, like wrapping chunks of bytes in headers that say how large the packet is, what it's for, etc.

Or it could be a pre-existing protocol that someone else has invented - in which case you can use a library implementation. Many people would use HTTP for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I have a few more follow up questions. The images are being edited in OpenCV's Mat format but being displayed  using BufferedImages, what method of transferring the images do you recommend? How can I make a button stop the server?

Comment: When the button is clicked, call serverThread.stop(). Any decent example of a server implementation will have a stop() method.

Comment: As for getting from BufferedImage to something to write to the network -- use the same method you would use to write to a file, but instead of using a FileOutputStream, write to whatever protocol you choose.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to initialise the Thread first then Start it and stop it when a button is clicked. Because I create it when I press the button

Comment: Doesn't matter when you initialise it, as long as it's before you start it!

Comment: Even if it created in a method and stopped in another method?